# asp net web form session timeout after redirect in chrome 84

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, redirect, webforms, session-timeout

My app (asp.net web form .net framework 4.5 on IIS version 6.2) connects to a payment gateway. 
 If I use Chrome browser(version 84) and if the user operations on the payment gateway takes longer than 90 seconds to redirect from gateway payment to my website, a session timeout occurs and the user is logged out.

Firefox and other browsers work correctly. 
**update**
I knew this problem is about '**SameSite attribute**' in latest version of chrome; Recent [updates to the standards on SameSite](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-00) propose protecting apps. 
but how can I solve this problem in asp.net web form application?

Answer (score 0):

try use cache instead of session , but consider cache is on app level , u can try add cache with random id

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not require code modification and instead uses web config or IIS configuration.

Comment: it is expired only on Chrome browser(version 84) ? or all chrome versions ?

Comment: expired on Chrome browser version > 80